# masonry + isotope + imagesLoaded not defined yii

Tags: javascript, yii, jquery-isotope, yii-extensions, masonry

Hello i´m new to web development. I´m struggling with a JS function using Yii 1.1: isotope-jquery.  Trying to show a masonry image gallery with infinite scrolling. If i leave it as it is it works, but when using images they get all overlapped at the end. i should use imagesLoaded, but applying it´s being a pain...

Original code:

```js
 $defaultCallback="
        function( newElements ) { 
        /* hide new items while they are loading*/ 
        var newElems = jQuery( newElements ); 
        \$isoContainer.isotope( 'appended', newElems, true );
        {$this->infiniteCallback}
        }";
```

Modified:

```js
function( newElements ) { 
        /* hide new items while they are loading*/ 
        var newElems = jQuery( newElements );
        \$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){         
            \$isoContainer.masonry( 'insert', newElems);
        });
        {$this->infiniteCallback}
        }"
```

Error on browser console:

```
["math:", 222, 2853] jquery.infinitescroll.js:171
["math:", 0, 2853] jquery.infinitescroll.js:171
["heading into ajax", Array[2]] jquery.infinitescroll.js:171
["Using HTML via .load() method"] jquery.infinitescroll.js:171
["contentSelector", div.items.isotope] jquery.infinitescroll.js:171
Uncaught ReferenceError: $newElems is not defined index.php?r=products:112(anonymous function) index.php?r=products:112opts.callback jquery.infinitescroll.js:159infscr_loadcallback jquery.infinitescroll.js:327infscr_ajax_callback jquery.infinitescroll.js:501jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:595jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:241jQuery.ajax.complete jquery.js:7465fire jquery.js:974self.fireWith jquery.js:1084done jquery.js:7818callback
```

i´ve tried several things, defining the var inside, passing parameters, but i cannot make it work...

probably it´s a newbie issue...

thanks for your help

Comment: Using isotope or masonry? Your update code has masonry

Comment: i´m using (trying) masonry layout mode, thanks

Comment: You haven't given enough info to solve your issue. You need to post more of your code. Better yet, make a jsfiddle. Also,  your using masonry but you seem to be loading isotope (?) `["contentSelector", div.items.isotope]`

Comment: ok first of all, thanks for helping me.  Createad a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/avvn7fp6/1/
Regarding masonry isotope question, i´m using yii framework and installed yii extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/isotope-jquery/ which lets you chose the masonry layout

Comment: Your fiddle is not user friendly! You need to add all your libraries (infinitescroll, bootstrap.js, etc) as external CDN resources and then add your specific code in the javascript panel. Way too much to wade thru until you do that. Also, you need to set jQuery as the library not plain javascript. Finally if your using isotope, you don't call it using masonry, `$isoContainer.masonry( 'insert', newElems);` different libraries.

Comment: yes, i saved the page, and pasted everything in there, it seemed the only way. I tried using library but couldn´t make it work. I solved the issue though, i played with code, and finally got to this: 
    function( newElements ) { 
  /* hide new items while they are loading*/ 
  var newElems = jQuery( newElements );
  \$isoContainer.imagesLoaded(function(){   
  \$isoContainer.isotope( 'appended', newElems,true);
  });

replaced $newElems with isoContainer, and followed your advice on using isotope instead of masonry. thanks @Macsupport

Comment: How about at least a vote up? ;-)

Comment: i would like to, but don´t have reputation to vote up yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the solution, and works like a charm!

```js
function( newElements ) { 
        /* hide new items while they are loading*/ 
        var newElems = jQuery( newElements );
        \$isoContainer.imagesLoaded(function(){         
        \$isoContainer.isotope( 'appended', newElems,true);
        });
```

thanks @Macsupport